# In ASP.NET MVC, where is the "best practice" place (folder) to put my Entity-Framework DataContext class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, directory-structure

I've seen a few projects with Entity Framework DataContext classes in the "Models" folder, but since it's not really a model, this doesn't feel right.

Currently my DataContext (along with the IDatabaseInitializer class) live in the root of my project, but that bugs me too.

Is there a common/best practice for this, or should I just leave them in the root or a folder called Data or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arguably it **is** the model, since it what maintains the state of your application. That's why people put it there.

If you're a good boy and use an abstraction/repository layer - it should go there.

If your Controllers are talking directly to the EF context (bad idea), then put it in the models folder - no need to physically hide something you're not logically abstracting.

Comment: The project I'm working on is so simple, abstracting the EF context away would just results in properties/methods that wrap the context one-to-one, so in this case, that would be overkill

Comment: Actually the one-to-one mapping is usually a sign of poor architecture and an anemic domain model. But if your working on a simple project where the controllers are working directly with the ctx, then put it in the models folder, or create a data folder.

Comment: I don't really follow why this suggests an anemic domain model, nor how to avoid one-for-one wrapping when the all access is almost exclusively in the form "from e in db.Entity where e.Field = value" :/

Comment: Check out this link posted in another answer: http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application The repository is just a one-to-one mapping. For something so simple, this feels like over-engineering to me.

Comment: @RPM1984 - Or it suggests you have a persistence as model application.  DDD isn't right for every application and if you don't have a strong domain and are not using a ubiquitous language with your customer it could be harmful.  An online forum or blog system is a perfect example.

Comment: @Danny Tuppeny - that example is very different to how i've done it. My repositories don't work with the context, they work with a generic repository, which is typed to the aggregate root of the type repository. So i have a `IRepository<Post>` which gets access to the `Post` object set, and can also work with comments, helpfuls, and any other relations. In that example, no point having multiple repositories IMO because each one can do everything the others can do (e.g they all have full access the context). My repositories enforce aggregate boundaries.

Comment: @jfar - agreed. I never said "use a proper repository, etc" i was simply highlighting issues with a one-to-one mapping for repositories. Not relevant to this particular case though as youve said.

Comment: I still don't really follow. What code should I be putting in the repository if it's not just going to map directly on to the DB? How can you even put code in there if it's generic? :/

Comment: @Danny - In short, when working with entities in EF, you should work with `ObjectSet<T>`, where `T` is the entity set, e.g `Posts`. So if my controllers request an `IRepository<Post>`, then my DI container will give it a `GenericRepository<Post>`. That implementation accepts the UoW/EF ctx, and only has access to `ObjectSet<Post>`. Kinda hard to explain in words. Anyway, since it's not the topic of this question - you can have a google around for EF 4 generic repository and im sure you'll find something.

Comment: Every example I can find online (eg. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImplRepositoryPatternEF.aspx) just has a repository that seems to pointlessly wrap the context, and even has loads of vile code to map queries (check out how big the SelectByKey method is). I fail to see what value this adds, other than potential for more bugs, more code, more testing, etc.

Comment: @Danny - think your missing the point. Again - look at the implementation of the `Add` method - `ctx.AddObject`. So the repository is working **directly with the context**. My repositories don't get access to the context, they get access to a `IUnitOfWork` which exposes only an `ObjectSet<T>`. I really don't agree with any of the implementations in the links you have provided. So the repository doesn't wrap the context, the UoW does. The repository can then be unit tested by passing in a mock unit of work. It all comes together when you start to use DI.

Comment: This answer may be outdated - a different take on the repository : http://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework/

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter. I put it in the Models folder because that's where all the database stuff goes into.

Answer (score 3):

At other places I've worked, VS Solutions were split into 3 projects:

- Presentation (MVC Site)
- Service (Business logic classes inc. POCO entities)
- Repository (Data access inc. EF Data Contexts)

Comment: That's a good point - though for trivial little web apps, that's probably a little overkill :-)

Comment: For small stuff I'd usually just put it in a `Data` or `Classes\Data` folder.

Answer (score 3):

I'll say its best practice to put it in model, as it is describe by MVC model and as I have been working on MVC for last 3 months I am very much into favour for this ... plus it gives you much flexibility when calling the EM classes ...

Answer (score 2):

Create different project with our data repository, add project to solution and reference it where need. Repository pattern make benefits to testing and changing your data layer in feature as need.

See http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: In that example the repository is just a one-to-one mapping. For something so simple, this feels like over-engineering to me.

Answer (score 1):

Just my thoughts on this; for any classes that are associated with Entity Framework, such as a DataContext class or a Base class, we put these in a DataFramework folder. As in theory whilst they extend EntityFramework in this context, there is no reason why they couldn't extend another database framework such as nHibernate.